# R TTR Package MACD Function

Tags: r

I am having difficulty reconciling the output of the MACD function in the R package TTR ver 0.22 (which by the way is an excellent package that I use a lot, thanks to Joshua).

A specific example is taken from daily closing prices for APPL 19 Feb 2013 to 22 May 2013.
I chose this dataset as there is a handy worked example in a spreadsheet [here](http://investexcel.net/how-to-calculate-macd-in-excel/).  The expected final values on 22 May 13 for macd and signal are 2.762 and 3.96 respectively (I have double checked these using standard EMA values 12,26,9, see example code below).  However the MACD function returns 0.63 and 0.903 for macd and signal values.  Am I missing something obvious ?

```
require(TTR)
require(xts)

## Apple APPL daily closes 19 Feb 13 to 22 May 13
## Data take from example : http://investexcel.net/how-to-calculate-macd-in-excel/
appl = c(459.99,448.85,446.06,450.81,442.8,448.97,444.57,441.4,430.47,420.05,431.14,425.66,430.58,431.72,437.87,428.43,428.35,432.5,443.66,455.72,454.49,452.08,452.73,461.91,463.58,461.14,452.08,442.66,428.91,429.79,431.99,427.72,423.2,426.21,426.98,435.69,434.33,429.8,419.85,426.24,402.8,392.05,390.53,398.67,406.13,405.46,408.38,417.2,430.12,442.78,439.29,445.52,449.98,460.71,458.66,463.84,456.77,452.97,454.74,443.86,428.85,434.58,433.26,442.93,439.66,441.35)
expected.last.macd = 2.7625612158
expected.last.signal = 3.9606012968

macd.maType='EMA'
fast=12
slow=26
sig=9

## 1. Call TTR MACD function and test last() values against expected values 
m = MACD(x=appl, nFast=fast, nSlow=slow, nSig=sig, maType = macd.maType )

actual.last.macd = last(m[,1])
actual.last.signal = last(m[,2])

cat('Test 1. TTR MACD\n')

if ( abs(expected.last.macd-actual.last.macd) > 1e-6 ) {
  cat('macd results differ: expected/actual', expected.last.macd, actual.last.macd, '\n')
} else {
  cat('macd results match\n')
}

if ( abs(expected.last.signal-actual.last.signal) > 1e-6 ) {
  cat('signal results differ: expected/actual', expected.last.signal, actual.last.signal, '\n')
} else {
  cat('signal results match\n')
}


## 2. Build our own MACD
ema.fast = EMA(x=appl, n = fast)
ema.slow = EMA(x=appl, n = slow)
macd = ema.fast - ema.slow
signal = EMA(x=macd, n=sig)

actual.last.macd = last(macd)
actual.last.signal = last(signal)

cat('Test 2. DIY MACD\n')
if ( abs(expected.last.macd-actual.last.macd) > 1e-6 ) {
  cat('macd results differ: expected/actual', expected.last.macd, actual.last.macd, '\n')
} else {
  cat('macd results match\n')
}

if ( abs(expected.last.signal-actual.last.signal) > 1e-6 ) {
  cat('signal results differ: expected/actual', expected.last.signal, actual.last.signal, '\n')
} else {
  cat('signal results match\n')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `percent=FALSE`:

```
R> m = MACD(x=appl, nFast=fast, nSlow=slow, nSig=sig, percent=FALSE)
```

From `?MACD`:

> percent: logical; if ‘TRUE’, the percentage difference between the
>             fast and slow moving averages is returned, otherwise the
>             difference between the respective averages is returned.

Comment: Joshua, thanks for the prompt response. That fixes it.